Acumatica remove Location attribute than what attribute we will use in this place
In previous version we use this attribute [Location(DisplayName = "Location", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
Acumatica also provided attribute [MfgLocationAvail(typeof(inventoryID), typeof(subItemID), typeof(siteID), false, true, KeepEntry = false, ResetEntry = true, Required = true)] but i dont want to use this attribute because i dont have to pass inventoryID, subItemID, siteID
What attribute i used for this LocationID?

You can try something like this
[LocationActiveAttribute(typeof(Where<Location.bAccountID, Equal<Current<ISPSShipFilter.customerID>>>), 
    DisplayName = "Location", DescriptionField = typeof(Location.descr))]
        

